# How to see that this set is not locally compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

In $(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$ I have that the set $A=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{\frac1n,n\in\mathbb{N}^*\}$.

We know that $A$ is not closed and not open. ($\bar{A}=\mathbb{R}, \mathring A=A\setminus\{0\}$)

If I suppose that it is locally compact i.e. each point of $A$ has a compact neighborhood, we can say that there exist an open set $\Omega \subset A$ but I have no idea how to continue.

> How to get a contradiction?

Comment: What is $B$? And what do you want to prove?

Comment: A not B sorry, i don't know what to do ? i need a hint , @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: Hint: try looking at closed neighbourhoods of $0$. You should be able to show that they are not compact, either by finding an irreducible infinite open cover (via a sequence of intervals) or by constructing a sequence with no convergent subsequence (remember $A$ is a metric space).

Comment: how [-r,r] is a compact ngbh of 0 i don't understand your idea @TheoBendit

Comment: I do not see a real connection between title and text of your question. I therefore vote to close it.

Comment: @PaulFrost i have a set not closed and not open i want to prove that is not locally compact

Comment: @Vrouvrou That's a compact neighbourhood of $0$ in $\Bbb{R}$. In $A$, it would have to be something of the form $[-r, r] \setminus \{1/n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ (or, at least, any closed neighbourhood of $0$ in $A$ would have to contain a neighbourhood of this form). Can you show this set is not compact?

Comment: why a closed ngbh ? i don't know how to do @TheoBendit

Comment: @Vrouvrou Given the space is Hausdorff (indeed, it is a metric space), every compact set must be closed. So, when searching for compact neighbourhoods, it suffices to look at closed neighbourhoods. I'd really rather not just present you with an answer, because I do think you'll be able to do it with a little prompting, but if it's really not working out, I can give you an answer.

Comment: i really don't know how to prove this @TheoBendit

Comment: @Vrouvrou OK, I guess I'll give you an answer then.

Comment: Please make the title of your question match the actual question. It is not true that a subset of $\Bbb{R}$ that is neither open nor closed is not locally compact (e.g., consider the half-open interval $[0, 1)$). Your specific example isn't locally compact, which ic probably best seen using sequential compactness (any neighbourhood of $0$ contains a sequence tending to $1/n$ for some $n$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Locally compact" = around every point, there is a compact neighbourhood. Since $A$ is a subspace of a metric space $\Bbb{R}$, it too is a metric space, and so compact sets must be closed. Thus, we are done if we can find a point such that every closed neighbourhood of this point is non-compact, then we have proven $A$ is not locally compact.

I suggest concentrating on $0 \in A$ (indeed, no other point will work). If we take a closed neighbourhood of $0$ in $A$, then it needs to be a closed neighbourhood $\mathcal{N}$ of $0$ in $\Bbb{R}$, intersected with $A$. We can shrink $\mathcal{N}$ as we like, since, if we take a closed subset of a compact set, then it too will be compact. We can always find a symmetric closed bounded interval in a closed neighbourhood $\mathcal{N}$ of $0$ (in $\Bbb{R}$), so we might as well take $\mathcal{N} = [-r, r]$ for some $r > 0$. That is, we need to show that
$$[-r, r] \cap A = [-r, r] \setminus \left\{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \Bbb{N}^* \right\}$$
is never a compact set!

How do we do this? We can pick our method here: either by using sequences, or open covers (we don't always get this choice in general topological spaces, but we do in metric spaces). The sequences method is usually easier to understand for struggling students, since sequential compactness is usually what is taught in real analysis courses.

Since $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$, we can find some $N$ such that
$$n > N \implies \left|\frac{1}{n} - 0\right| < r \implies n \in [-r, r].$$
Let's fix such an $n$. Then, let's try to define a sequence in $[-r, r] \cap A$ that converges to $\frac{1}{n}$ in $\Bbb{R}$. Such a sequence must have no convergent subsequence in $A$. We can simply define:
$$x_m = \frac{1}{n} - 2^{-(m + 1)} \cdot\left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right).$$
As $m \to \infty$, we clearly have
$$x_m \to \frac{1}{n} - 0 \cdot\left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right) = \frac{1}{n},$$
and
$$0 < 2^{-(m+1)} < 1 \implies \frac{1}{n+1} < x_m < \frac{1}{n}.$$
That is, $x_m$ lies between the points $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n+1}$, both of which lie in $[-r, r]$, and all such point between lie in $A$. So, $x_m \in [-r, r] \cap A$ for all $m$.

Since $x_m \to \frac{1}{n}$ in $\Bbb{R}$, then any subsequence would converge in $\Bbb{R}$ to $\frac{1}{n}$. Since $A$ is a subspace of $\Bbb{R}$, then convergence of a subsequence to a point $L \in [-r, r] \cap A$ would imply that the subsequence would converge to $L$ in $\Bbb{R}$, but $L \neq \frac{1}{n}$, which contradicts uniqueness of limits.

This means that $x_m$ has no convergent subsequence in $[-r, r] \cap A$, despite $x_m \in [-r, r] \cap A$. This means that $[-r, r] \cap A$ is not compact, and so no neighbourhood of $0$ in $A$ is compact. That is, $A$ is not locally compact.

---

Regarding your title, it is true that open subsets and closed subsets of locally compact spaces are compact, but the converse is not true! For example, $(0, 1]$ is locally compact in $\Bbb{R}$. So, it is not valid simply to show that the set is neither closed nor open in a locally compact space and conclude that it is not locally compact.